# No wireless routers are detected on Ubunutu 12.10

Tags: wireless

I am using Toshiba Satellite C-A50 laptop with Atheros AR9565 card. Even though the "wlan0" interface is shown in "ifconfig" no Wireless Routers are coming up to check a connection. "Enable Wireless" is ticked in the Network connection drop down."eth0" interface is working fine. I have installed compat-wireless-3.6.8-1-snpc "ath9k" driver for the wireless. The "dmesg" command in the terminal shows "[ 1972.160105] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready".
Same Atheros wireless card works properly in Windows 7. Also kernel version. uname -r result 3.5.0-39-generic
I am a beginner in Linux Please help me out.

lshw -c network result.

```
   *-network               
   description: Wireless interface

   product: AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter

   vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.

   physical id: 0

   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0

   logical name: wlan0

   version: 01

   serial: 24:fd:52:4d:50:dc

   width: 64 bits

   clock: 33MHz

   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless


   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.5.0-39-generic 

   firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn

   resources: irq:17 memory:d3400000-d347ffff memory:9fb00000-9fb0ffff

   *-network

   description: Ethernet interface

   product: Atheros Communications Inc.

   vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.

   physical id: 0

   bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0

   logical name: eth0

   version: 10

   serial: 7c:05:07:87:5c:bc

   size: 100Mbit/s

   capacity: 100Mbit/s

   width: 64 bits

   clock: 33MHz


   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 

    10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation

   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=1.2.3 

     duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.4.58 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes 

    port=twisted 

    pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:18 memory:d1000000-d103ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
```

---

lspci result

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM 

Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family 

PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor 

Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI 

Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 

MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB 

Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High 

Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express 

Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express 

Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express 

Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB 

Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA 

Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1140 (rev a1)

08:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. Device 10a0 (rev 10)
```

---

ifconfig result.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7c:05:07:87:5c:bc  
          inet addr:192.168.4.58  Bcast:192.168.4.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7e05:7ff:fe87:5cbc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9904 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4521 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3059787 (3.0 MB)  TX bytes:917645 (917.6 KB)
          Interrupt:18 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:978 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:978 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:157336 (157.3 KB)  TX bytes:157336 (157.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:fd:52:4d:50:dc  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: Same Atheros wireless card works properly in Windows 7. Also I forgot to mention the kernel version.

uname -r result
3.5.0-39-generic

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Vineethanand! You can always [edit] your question to include more information by clicking on the `edit` link right underneath it ([screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/kCxmCWD.png)). So go ahead and edit your question to include what you wrote in the comment.

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.

Comment: The result is copied to the following link: http://pastebin.com/ACFrTzvH

Comment: @WildMan Please help my dear friend.

Comment: Please tell us where you got this driver from compat-wireless-3.6.8-1-snpc and what is the link to the directions for installing it.

Comment: @WildMan:Got the driver from this link: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Download/stable#compat-wireless_3.6_stable_releases.
In this package Readme.txt file contains the steps to install the driver.I installed "ath9k" from the available wireless drivers.
I list the steps here.

1. sudo ./scripts/driver-select ath9k.
2. sudo make.
3. sudo make install.
4. sudo modprobe ath9k.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the driver and install this one.
[3.5](http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.5/compat-wireless-3.5.4-1-snpc.tar.bz2)

First remove the current driver:

```
cd <to the path of the old driver/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1-snpc>

sudo su

./scripts/driver-select restore

./scripts/driver-select ath9k

make clean
```

Then drag the file to your desktop right click on it and select extract here:

```
cd Desktop/compat-wireless-3.5.4-1-snpc
sudo su

./scripts/driver-select ath9k

make

make install

exit
```

After build and installation unload modules and drivers:

```
sudo make unload

sudo modprobe ath9k
```

Edit: Please do

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

Then:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Then unplug your ehternet connection and see if your wifi can connect.

Comment: Followed the steps as you mentioned.The "wlan0" interface is still coming up after installing the given ath9k driver. But the nearby routers are not shown in the drop down menu on the desktop. The same condition as that of before.The Ethernet LAN driver "alx" in compat-wireless-3.6.8-1-snpc from the new link works fine

Comment: I ran the wireless_script and the results are copied in this link:http://pastebin.com/gTnw6rbn

Comment: Please post the output of: `modinfo ath9k`

Comment: The results are posted in this [link](http://pastebin.com/ZVee4enV)

Comment: The output of "modinfo ath9k" are copied in the above mentioned link

Comment: Please help my dear friend.Any further observations?

Comment: After reboot your device is showing in modinfo, that is good. Please run a new script and post the results so we can see if it is scanning now and several other things. If not there may be an issue with this driver.

Comment: The results of the script are posted in this [link](http://pastebin.com/wdacP4Vj).

Comment: Any further observations from this result.My driver working properly.?

Comment: I could find one more thing that sometimes some wireless routers are getting detected. But not able to connect.The Wireless router may disappear from the drop down after some time also.

Comment: The information you posted does not show your wifi scanning at all but if it does sometimes then the last commands I added may make it connect.

Comment: I had a run of the wireless_script in between an attempt to associate with the Router which came up in the dropdown list.The results are posted in this [link](http://pastebin.com/ggZadkCW). Also the kernel version is now 3.5.0-40-generic

Comment: Can you please have a look into this. When i try for an association with different routers it fails all the time.

Comment: I have re installed the driver along with the 'edit' what you have mentioned. I could find [these](http://pastebin.com/5AFX6aFS) messages while giving the make command. Is there any error?

Comment: I added a different driver that I think will work better.